# Please share one scenario where always call base class method by using derived class object in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Program  
{  
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        Teacher Teacher= new Teacher();  
        Teacher.ShowInfo();  
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }    
} 

public class Person  
{  
  public virtual void ShowInfo()  
  {  
    Console.WriteLine("I am Person");  
  }  
}  


public class Teacher : Person  
{  
  public override void ShowInfo()  
  {  
    Console.WriteLine("I am Teacher");  
  }  
}
```

i want output as:-
"I am Person"

Is it possible to use virtual and override without using base keyword.

That means i want to call base method by using derived class object as created im main() method.

Comment: Then just remove ShowInfo method from Teacher... output will be "I am Person"

Comment: Is it a sort of challenge given by a teacher: *"do not use `base` keyword, to display "I am Person" from `Main` method"* or what?

Comment: Are you looking for: `public new void ShowInfo()` in `Teacher` with `((Person)Teacher).ShowInfo();` ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program  
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Teacher Teacher = new Teacher();
        ((Person)Teacher).ShowInfo();    //"I am Person"
        Teacher.ShowInfo();              //"I am Teacher"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual void ShowInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Person");
    }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public new void ShowInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Teacher");
    }
}
```